# C++ Program, Console/Terminal Output. How to implement "updating text"

Tags: c++, terminal, cout

I am writing a C++ program, which runs a long data analysis algorithm. It takes several days to finish running, so it is useful to have a prompt which outputs the "percentage complete" every time a new loop in the program starts so that the user (me) knows the computer isn't sitting in an infinite loop somewhere or has crashed.

At the moment I am doing this the most basic way, by computing the percentage complete as a floating point number and doing:

```
std::cout << "Percentage complete: " << percentage_complete << " %" << std::endl;
```

But, when the program has a million loops to run, this is kind of messy. In addition, if the terminal scrollback is only 1000 lines, then I lose the initial debug info printed out at the start once the program is 0.1 % complete.

I would like to copy an idea I have seen in other programs, where instead of writing a new line each time with the percentage complete, I simply replace the last line written to the terminal with the new percentage complete.

How can I do this? Is that possible? And if so, can this be done in a cross platform way? Are there several methods of doing this?

I am unsure how to describe what I am trying to do perfectly clearly, so I hope that this clear enough that you understand what I am trying to do.

To clarify, rather than seeing this:

```
Running program.
Debug info:
Total number of loops: 1000000

Percentage complete: 0 %
Percentage complete: 0.001 %
Percentage complete: 0.002 %
.
.
.
Percentage complete: 1.835 %
```

I would like to see this:

```
Running program.
Debug info:
Total number of loops: 1000000

Percentage complete: 1.835 %
```

And then on the next loop the terminal should update to this:

```
Running program.
Debug info:
Total number of loops: 1000000

Percentage complete: 1.836 %
```

I hope that's enough information.

(Okay, so this output would actually be for 100000 steps, not 1000000.)

Comment: It completely depends on your terminal. On a basic Linux terminal emulator, a `\r` character ought to be enough. There are loads of duplicates of this though, so I shan't elaborate.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Surely this wouldn't work in the case where the number of digits printed changed? IE: From 1.999% to 2% - which would print 2%999%? (Actually: 1.999 % to 2 %99%)

Comment: That's right; you'd need leading or trailing spaces to mask the old input where the new input doesn't already. But that's easy. And, as I said, this is a duplicate so you can find all this detail already written-about elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `\n` or `std::endl`, use `\r`. The difference is that the latter returns the cursor to the beginning if the line without a new line.

Disclaimer (as per Lightness' objections): This is not necessarily portable, so YMMV.

Comment: Same comment as just a second ago for this though: Surely this wouldn't work in the case where the number of digits printed changed? IE: From 1.999% to 2% - which would print 1.999 % then 2 %99% ?

Comment: But it's a step in the right direction, thanks for the info

Comment: Add spaces after the percent sign if you want to be safe.

Comment: `\r` can be used with `cout` as well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ old habits die hard. When I want more control of the formatting I tend to revert to printf.

Comment: Could use std::fixed I guess?

Comment: @user3728501 Of course, and `std::setw()`, `std::right` accordingly.

Comment: @user3728501 the simplest would be to add about 7 spaces assuming there won't be more than 8 figures. But if it's just for debugging, as seems to be indicted in the question that should be enough. If it's for production, consider using a fixed precision or a string of n-m spaces.

Comment: This is terminal specific. And try making it work when redirecting output to a file.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit out of curiosity, what terminal doesn't work with this?

Comment: @AviGinsburg: A near-infinite list. I'm not going to enumerate them, but `cmd.exe` comes to mind for a start. Fortunately, _I don't need to_, because writing portable C++ code (and in the absence of a specific technology having been stated in the question) requires that we not even get to the point where such a list is required. Besides, I literally just gave you an example of when this will lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've actually done that with tee. It's a bit ugly but readable. And it wouldn't be much worse than OPs current status.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not everything is portable. Try redirecting stdout for *part* of a program. But there are some solutions/nonportable hacks that work.

Comment: Right, so state the target platform/technology! Otherwise the answer is incomplete/misleading as purporting to be "a C++ solution" when it's not :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Too many to enumerate ;) but point taken.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `cmd.exe` in my experience works fine with `\r`.